# Cygwin's gcc compiler warning from mpfr library

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, gcc-warning, mpfr

I'm using Cygwin with gcc and I'm trying to run a quick sample program that uses mpfr library and I have this line of code:

```
mpfr_out_str (stdout, 10, 0, s, MPFR_RNDD);
```

And I'm getting this compiler warning.

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mpfr_out_str’; did you mean ‘mpf_out_str’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     mpfr_out_str (stdout, 10, 0, s, MPFR_RNDD);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
     mpf_out_str
```

Yet when I looked online at various sites for simple examples of use and even looked though the mpfr docs they were all using

```
mpfr_out_str(...)
```

...

So why is the compiler complaining to me that I should be using

```
mpf_out_str
```

Instead?

---

--- *main.c* --- [online example](http://www.mpfr.org/sample.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gmp.h"
#include "mpfr.h"

int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    mpfr_t s, t, u;

    mpfr_init2 (t, 200);
    mpfr_set_d (t, 1.0, MPFR_RNDD);
    mpfr_init2 (s, 200);
    mpfr_set_d (s, 1.0, MPFR_RNDD);
    mpfr_init2 (u, 200);
    for ( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) {
        mpfr_mul_ui (t, t, i, MPFR_RNDU);
        mpfr_set_d (u, 1.0, MPFR_RNDD);
        mpfr_div (u, u, t, MPFR_RNDD);
        mpfr_add (s, s, t, MPFR_RNDD);
    }
    printf( "Sum is " );
    mpfr_out_str (stdout, 10, 0, s, MPFR_RNDD); // this line here
    putchar ('\n');
    mpfr_clear(s);
    mpfr_clear(t);
    mpfr_clear(u);

    return 0;
}
```

Also for some reason I think Cygwin with gcc is having issues linking against gmp and mprf... I'm using gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC).

Note: In my main.c I originally had the includes the same as the online example:

```
#include <...>
```

I previously mentioned that I had trouble linking against the library and tried hundreds of different ways to try and link against them, too many to list here. So eventually I took a copy of the libs and their headers and just pasted them directly into the same folder that contains main.c and this is why you see my includes as

#include "..."

instead of the original online sample.

---

Mind you I'm not all that familiar with `Unix-POSIX` environment, operations or command line arguments for compiling c/c++ code on a Unix environment that uses either gcc/g++ or clang. I've primarily been accustomed to Visual Studio, windows and cmd and it's features, settings and syntax. Right now I'm learning as I go from documentation, websites, online tutorials both text & video, etc.

---

This may be a topic of discussion for a different question, but I think that it might relate into partially answering this posted question.

When one installs Cygwin and then decides to install gcc/g++ as opposed to mingw's clang; should gmp and mpir already be installed or do they have to be installed manually and if so: in what order? Does gmp & mpir need to be installed before gcc or can it be installed after? Does the order make a difference in how gcc is able to link against such libraries? Would the proper installation order and linking of libraries resolve this compiler warning?

Comment: have you included `#include <mpfr.h>` ?

Comment: Did you `#include <gmp.h>` and `#include <mpfr.h>` ?

Comment: test this sample code: http://www.mpfr.org/sample.html

Comment: if the include is missing, then it's a duplicate all right.

Comment: no reaction from OP so it's probably the issue. I'm closing this. Feel free to ping me if it's a different issue.

Comment: Yes I have both files included.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and that is the same exact example that I followed.

Comment: I have reopened. Can you [edit] your question to create a [mcve] (even if it's a copy of the example), also specify gcc version.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I made some updates to my original post.

Comment: mpir is a fork of gmp, you probably mean mpfr in your question? At least with mingw-w64, you get a package manager and can just tell it you want mpfr, and it will manage the dependencies for you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you also get the warning if you compile the code with g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I haven't tried to compile it as C++. At the moment I only build GMP and MPFR for C. "This is not the underlying version". I'm linking against the distributions from their respective GNU websites.

Comment: You know, trying to compile it as C++ is just changing 2 letters in your command line. It will still use your existing GMP/MPFR just fine.

Comment: @MarcGlisse True, c++ can compile c code.

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains how things work in MPFR and GMP internals and the possible cause of this warning.

First, the `mpfr_out_str` prototype in `mpfr.h` is:

```
size_t mpfr_out_str (FILE*, int, size_t, mpfr_srcptr, mpfr_rnd_t);
```

Note that it uses the `FILE` type, which is not necessarily defined, so that this prototype must not be declared unconditionally, like in GMP. MPFR declares this prototype under the condition:

```
#if defined (_GMP_H_HAVE_FILE) || defined (MPFR_USE_FILE)
```

`_GMP_H_HAVE_FILE` comes from GMP internals and should be defined when `gmp.h` has detected that `FILE` is defined. But note that this is only a heuristic since the C standard does not specify a way to do such detection, and this may be the cause of the warning (see below); `gmp.h` currently has:

```
#if defined (FILE)                                              \
  || defined (H_STDIO)                                          \
  || defined (_H_STDIO)               /* AIX */                 \
  || defined (_STDIO_H)               /* glibc, Sun, SCO */     \
  || defined (_STDIO_H_)              /* BSD, OSF */            \
  || defined (__STDIO_H)              /* Borland */             \
  || defined (__STDIO_H__)            /* IRIX */                \
  || defined (_STDIO_INCLUDED)        /* HPUX */                \
  || defined (__dj_include_stdio_h_)  /* DJGPP */               \
  || defined (_FILE_DEFINED)          /* Microsoft */           \
  || defined (__STDIO__)              /* Apple MPW MrC */       \
  || defined (_MSL_STDIO_H)           /* Metrowerks */          \
  || defined (_STDIO_H_INCLUDED)      /* QNX4 */                \
  || defined (_ISO_STDIO_ISO_H)       /* Sun C++ */             \
  || defined (__STDIO_LOADED)         /* VMS */                 \
  || defined (__DEFINED_FILE)         /* musl */
#define _GMP_H_HAVE_FILE 1
#endif
```

Alternatively, the user can define `MPFR_USE_FILE` before including `mpfr.h` (this should normally not be necessary as auto-detection should work).

Now, the warning message the OP gets is:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mpfr_out_str’; did you mean ‘mpf_out_str’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     mpfr_out_str (stdout, 10, 0, s, MPFR_RNDD);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
     mpf_out_str
```

**EDIT** I also get this warning when I use the incorrect code:

```
#include "gmp.h"
#include "mpfr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

(`<stdio.h>` not being included *before* `mpfr.h`). I don't know why gcc suggests `mpf_out_str` instead: one can check with `gcc -E` that it has not been declared either! And indeed, `gmp.h` has:

```
#define mpf_out_str __gmpf_out_str
#ifdef _GMP_H_HAVE_FILE
__GMP_DECLSPEC size_t mpf_out_str (FILE *, int, size_t, mpf_srcptr);
#endif
```

while `_GMP_H_HAVE_FILE` is not defined.

So, there would be the same issue with GMP. I suggest to define `MPFR_USE_FILE` before including `mpfr.h` as said above and as documented in the MPFR manual (note: the constraint "before the first inclusion of `mpfr.h` or `gmp.h`" is now obsolete, AFAIK). A bug could be reported against GMP so that it detects the `FILE` definition with Cygwin too.

Note: the above warning is from the compiler itself; linking issues are not involved.

Comment: A quick google search seems to indicate cygwin uses _STDIO_H, which is in the list.

Comment: What a delightful and excellent answer. Very easy to follow and understand in plain words English. Pointed out what could be the culprit by showing examples of how the same warning can be generated in other ways. Very nice answer. I gave you an up vote for now. I'll have to dig into a little more; the manuals and docs are a bit of a tough read... mainly because they assume you know Unix environments Posix, and there lies my difficulties for the time being. I understand C code a little bit, buts its been years since I've worked with C, for the past few decades I've been working in Visual C++.

Comment: Now, for the weird suggestion is that coming from the gcc compiler directly, or could it have something to do with the internals of Cygwin..., or a combination of both?

Comment: Actually the suggestion is not weird (at least from gcc's POV), the macro mpf_out_str is defined even if the function is not declared.